# why jquery autocomplete doesnt work on https (secure pages)?

Tags: jquery-ui, ssl, autocomplete, https

I am trying to make jquery autocomplete to be work on https (secured pages) pages but its not showing any dropdown.
I searched on this issue and found that its security issue.

can any one tell me how to turn on this autocomplete dropdown on https pages.

here is my code to jquery autocomplete :

```
function zipAutoCompletet(prefix) {
  jQuery("#" + prefix + "_zip").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
          style: "full",
          maxRows: 12,
          postalcode_startsWith: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
          response(jQuery.map(data.postalCodes, function (item) {
            return {
              label: item.placeName + (item.adminCode1 ? ", " + item.adminCode1 : "") + ", " + item.postalCode + ", " + item.countryCode,
              value: item.postalCode
            }
          }));
          jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '188px');
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var myString = new String(ui.item.label);
      var address = myString.split(',')
          jQuery('#' + prefix + '_city').val(address[0]);
      jQuery('#' + prefix + '_city').addClass('activated');
      jQuery('#' + prefix + '_city').trigger('change');
      jQuery('#' + prefix + '_city').parents('.row').removeClass('error-row')
        jQuery('#' + prefix + '_city').parents('.row').addClass('ok-row')
          var countryCode = address[3] ? address[3] : address[2]
              countryCode = jQuery.trim(countryCode);
      var countryName = jQuery('#' + prefix + '_country option[value="' + jQuery.trim(countryCode) + '"]').text()
          jQuery('#countryContainer .jqTransformSelectWrapper span').html(countryName)
            jQuery('#countryContainer .jqTransformSelectWrapper').addClass('selected-jqtranform');
      jQuery('#' + prefix + '_country').parents('.row').addClass('ok-row')
        jQuery('#' + prefix + '_country').parents('.row').removeClass('error-row')
          jQuery('#' + prefix + '_country').val(jQuery.trim(countryCode))
            var stateCode = address[2] ? address[1] : '';
      stateCode = jQuery.trim(stateCode)
        if (countryCode == 'US') {
          var base = base_url;
          base = base.replace("https", "http");
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: base + "/getStateName",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
              stateCode: stateCode
            },
            success: function (data) {
              stateName = data
                jQuery('#jc_state').val(stateName);
              jQuery('#jc_state').addClass('activated');
              jQuery('#jc_state').parents('.row').removeClass('error-row')
                jQuery('#jc_state').parents('.row').addClass('ok-row')
                  jQuery('#jc_state').trigger('change');
              formValidate();
            }
          });
        } else {
          stateName = stateCode
            jQuery('#jc_state').val(stateName);
          jQuery('#jc_state').addClass('activated');
          jQuery('#jc_state').parents('.row').removeClass('error-row')
            jQuery('#jc_state').parents('.row').addClass('ok-row')
              jQuery('#jc_state').trigger('change');
          formValidate();
        }
      jQuery('#' + prefix + '_zip').parents('.row').addClass('ok-row')
        jQuery('#' + prefix + '_zip').parents('.row').removeClass('error-row');
    },
    open: function () {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      if (ui.item === null) {
        jQuery("#" + prefix + "_zip").parents('.row').removeClass('ok-row');
        jQuery("#" + prefix + "_zip").parents('.row').addClass('error-row');
        $("#" + prefix + "_zip").val('');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I am using above code for zipcode field.This code works fine on non-https pages it works fine but when I tried it with https pages it doesnt shows.

any solutions are welcome.

Comment: Have you checked same origin policy condition

Comment: same origin condition policy means ?

Comment: what is domain name of your page? Same origin policy prohibits the browser from sending ajax request to a domain which is different than the page's domain. In your case the page which sends the ajax request must be from the `ws.geonames.org` domain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy in this page you can look at the `Origin determination rules`

Comment: Just to add a little bit to what @ArunPJohny said, your browser prohibits sending ajax requests across different domains however you may be interested in using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to accomplish this. JSONP (or json with padding) allows communications across different domains.

Comment: thanks @ArunPJohny but is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You have to look at `jsonp` based solutions as suggested by @War10ck

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes already I am using JSONP response..Is there any way to implement autcomplete ?

Comment: As you can see in my code I have used jsonp data type.have look on my code

Comment: can you share the response from the server

Comment: If you want to use jsonp, your server should support the jsonp callback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23705/discussion-between-akki-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I looked into the service provider they are supporting `jsonp` and the following sample worked

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?callback=?", 
          { 'postalcode_startsWith': request.term, maxRows: 12, style: "full" }, 
          function(data) {
              if(data.postalCodes){
                  var x = $.map(data.postalCodes, function(v, i){
                      console.log(v)
                      return {
                          label: v.placeName + ' - ' + v.postalCode, 
                          v: v.postalCode
                      }
                  });
                  response(x);
              }
          }
        );        
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k58U5/1/)