# jQuery Autocomplete, source JSON through API

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am not completely familiar with the jQuery autocomplete so I hope you can give me some idea about how I am going to achieve my task.

I have a the following url:

```
http://localhost/contactApi.do?mobile=614321
```

at which the mobile can be whole or part of a contact number. I designed this API call a while a go and When you put this url in a browser and enter, you get a JSON response displayed on the front end with all the matching results (all mobiles like this number you enter in the url).

My question is how can I use (or can I?) this url as of my autocomlete source?

Like if I want to use something like the example given by jQuery UI demos, how can I pass the mobile to the url?

I have seen some places they have used such a source like the following:

```
source:"http://localhost/contactApi.do?mobile=?"
```

Now how does it work, this ? will pick what I type everytime or what?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think it should work .. have you tested it out?

Comment: No the thing is I have nt got enough idea on how to set it ready to be tested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at something like

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/contactApi.do?mobile=614321", 
          {  }, 
          function(data) {
              if(data){
                  response(data);
              }
          }
        );        
    }
});
```

The data should be array like `[{value: <value>, text: <display-text>}, ....]`.

You can also look at the following samples
[why jquery autocomplete doesnt work on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607734/why-jquery-autocomplete-doesnt-work-on-https-secure-pages/14624808#14624808)

Comment: what is `?` is it a parameter? who is providing value for it?