# ajax url post on https url

Tags: php, ajax

Since I am using SSL connection in my website, I am trying to check the port where the user open the url (http/https):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
    ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
  $protocol = 'https://';
}
else {
  $protocol = 'http://';
}
```

It works great for the link of external file like css and js.

However, by checking the port, I am not able to post something with ajax.

```
 <input type='submit' value="LOGIN" onclick="return checkLogin()">

        function checkLogin() {
            var cUsername = $('[id$=userEmail]').val();
            var cPassword = $('[id$=userPassword]').val();
            var cartItems = cartItemsToJSON();

            var dataString = "username=" + cUsername + "&password=" + cPassword  + "&cartItems=" + cartItems;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo $protocol; ?>"+location.hostname+" /member/actions/config-login2.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html) {
```

When I click login, it doesn't run to the `config-lgin2.php, but it only shows my credential on the browser.

I am wondering if I miss something here. Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you making cross domain post or you are submitting on the same domain ?  Please use the Fiddler or chrome developer tool to see what's happening with the request you are sending.

Comment: No cross domain. Only the port which is different: sometime it is in https, and sometime it is in http. Depends on where the user open it. As default it will be in http.

Comment: Can you post the complete code after you do it after success callback of AJAX request ? Also please check once the html received in the success call back.

Comment: One more point make the cache : false in the attribute otherwise browser will the cache locally the response.

Comment: The code gave from Heman is only working if I login from http port. But if I login from https port, the problem is there. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use fully qualified URLs, please try with a relative URI.

Instead of specifying url as ....

```
  url: "<?php echo $protocol; ?>"+location.hostname+" /member/actions/config-login2.php"
```

specify as,

```
  url: "member/actions/config-login2.php"
```

in the AJAX call

If it does not work, JSONP is a nice alternative to look for

Please view this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607734/why-jquery-autocomplete-doesnt-work-on-https-secure-pages)

Comment: Can you show me how to turn my code in jsonp. it still doesn't work with relative url.

Comment: hi alisa, can you tell me what message are you getting in the developer console?

Comment: JSONP is required if you are making cross domain request. I do not think JSONP is the solution here.

Comment: @Hemant, no error message there. I try to alert anything there, and it alert what it is. But still I am unable to login.

Comment: @Devesn, can you suggest me a solution, please? I do really need a help.

Comment: Try accessing the file in the same location as the page you are requesting with in the AJAX call.If it works, please (PHP) include the file config-login2 in that file

Comment: It works lol. I forget to change the GET to POST. thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, no. It only works on http. When I login from https port, the problem is still exist.

Comment: Can you access using relative URL a page on the same location as the page you are viewing via AJAX?

Comment: Yes, I use relative URL now. But it only works when I login from http port. If I login from https port it dosn't post the data. It shows my credential on browser.

Comment: Until a viable solution is not visible, please enable CORS at the page you are accessing via by using the code in config-login2.php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With"); use  fully qualified URLs as before [urls in the question you have stated] and let me know